# android camera intent with external camera app, return to original activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

If a user has an external camera app, such as camera+ that is set as their camera default, how do I make sure that after capturing a photo, it will go back to my original application activity?

```
       public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.photo_camera_button:
                Intent photoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(photoIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST);
            break;
            }
        }

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                ImageView imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ReturnedImageView);
                imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            }

        }
    }
```

This application is supposed to capture an image and send it back to an imageview, but after capturing a photo, the camera application is still there. I would like it to go back, or would I have to set up from scratch a new camera application?

Although, I would like it to use camera+ features and then when the user saves the image (typically it'll go to my SDcard, I believe) it'll kill the app, and then go back to my activity? Maybe override something?

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem with the stock Camera app on a GS2, but it only happens if I tap the screen to specify the focal point.  If I leave the focus alone, it returns as it should.

Answer (score 0):

What your asking is very hard to answer as i dnt know weather your third party app provide the feature of throwing back the result .You question could be answered properly if you have code of that third party app / see the doc weather they offer there app to be used by some third party

And developing new camera app by your self is not a such big task .